# How to create a vocabulary and populate it with terms using features

Tags: taxonomy-terms, features

I'd like to create a feature that creates a vocabulary and populates it with taxonomy terms.

Creating a vocabulary is easy with features and it can be done using UI (I only need to select the desired existing vocabulary and add it as dependency and a file features.taxonomy will be created)

However, there's no way to export terms to a feature, so I created a feature_name.install file and added the following function on it:

```
/**
 * Implements hook_install().
 */
function feature_name_install() {
  // Populates 'Vocabulary name' vocabulary with taxonomy terms.
  $vocabulary = taxonomy_vocabulary_machine_name_load('vocabulary_machine_name');
  $terms = array();

  $terms[] = t('Term 1');
  $terms[] = t('Term 2');
  $terms[] = t('Term 3');

  foreach($terms as $name) {
    $term = new stdClass();
    $term->vid = $vocabulary->vid;
    $term->name = $name;
    taxonomy_term_save($term);
  }
}
```

The problem with this code is that when installing the feature it is loaded before creating the vocabulary so tries to add terms to a vocabulary that does not exist yet and produces an error.

I have tried using [hook_post_features_enable_feature](http://drupalcontrib.org/api/drupal/contributions!features!features.api.php/function/hook_post_features_enable_feature/7) but I didn't succeeded (I may be using a wrong syntaxis, see code below).

```
/**
 * Implements hook_post_features_enable_feature($component).
 */
function feature_name_post_features_enable_feature($component) {
  $component = 'feature_name';
  // Populates 'Vocabulary name' vocabulary with taxonomy terms.
  $vocabulary = taxonomy_vocabulary_machine_name_load('vocabulary_machine_name');
  $terms = array();

  $terms[] = t('Term 1');
  $terms[] = t('Term 2');
  $terms[] = t('Term 3');

  foreach($terms as $name) {
    $term = new stdClass();
    $term->vid = $vocabulary->vid;
    $term->name = $name;
    taxonomy_term_save($term);
  }
}
```

Can anyone tell me how to solve this?

Answer (score 1):

The problem with exporting content like taxonomy terms is keeping the taxonomy id intact when migrating it from site to site which is exactly what the features extension module [UUID Features](https://drupal.org/project/uuid_features) solves by using the UUID api:

> The UUID Features Integration module provides a mechanism for
>   exporting content (nodes, taxonomy, fields) into a features module.
>   What's that you say? You thought features was only for configuration?
>   This module is meant to be used in the cases where certain pieces of
>   content straddle the line between pure content and configuration.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like your problem has to do with $component.  The vocabulary isn't complete until $component == 'taxonomy' - you should do an if on this before trying to create terms.

Answer (score 1):

Adding a vocabulary programmatically is just as easy as adding terms. You could use the same hook_install() function you've built for your term, and insert the vocabulary first.

```
function feature_name_install() {
  $vocab = new stdClass();
  $vocab->name = "My vocabulary name";
  $vocab->machine_name = "my_vocabulary_name";
  taxonomy_vocabulary_save($vocab);

  // Note, you could also attempt to load the vocabulary by machine name first,
  // which would allow you to take action if a vocabulary using your name
  // already exists (either delete it, or error out, or...)


  $vid = $vocab->vid;  // $vocab object now has the vocabulary ID

  // ...continue as you were in peace
```

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately the vocabulary provided by the feature won't be available using that hook, you'll have to use hook_post_features_rebuild() instead.